# How do I change a div with the video's title when a relevant video is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube-api

I'm trying to have a div with the currently playing video's title change when a user clicks a relevant video (when the video ends), so that the correct title is displayed. The problem is, I don't see anything in the api that alerts me that the video has changed. Is there an event I can listen for to detect that the source has changed?

I'm not sure it'll help, but this is what I have currently:

```js
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'BOMWNgejuPc',
    playerVars: {
      // 'controls': 0,
      'autoplay': 0,
      'disablekb': 1,
      'enablejsapi': 1,
      'fs': 1,
      'iv_load_policy': 3,
      // 'rel': 0,
      'showinfo': 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // Update title with current video title
  $('#title').text(player.getVideoData().title);
}
```

```html
<h3 id="title">Title</h3>
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for a player state change. Theoretically you could use the "video cued" event, but it seems to not be firing on a consistent basis for some reason right now so you'll need a workaround ... some combination of tracking when one video ends and another one starts. Set up a listener in your Player object with something like this:

```
var player,
new_video_started=false;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'BOMWNgejuPc',
    playerVars: {
      // 'controls': 0,
      'autoplay': 0,
      'disablekb': 1,
      'enablejsapi': 1,
      'fs': 1,
      'iv_load_policy': 3,
      // 'rel': 0,
      'showinfo': 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // Update title with current video title
  $('#title').text(player.getVideoData().title);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === -1) { // meaning that the video is in an 'unstarted' state, which happens when a new video is loading
    new_video_unstarted=true;
  }
  if (event.data === 1&&new_video_unstarted) { // when the new video starts playing, the metadata is available for querying
    $('#title').text(player.getVideoData().title);
    new_video_unstarted=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, but for my purposes, it's a bit inconvenient. I have the player default to autoplay = 0, so the title won't update until the user hits play. Are there any other indicators to when the metadata is available?